# How to configure module.alias properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-javascript, react-starter-kit

I would like to use `resolve.alias` feature from webpack in my projects using [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit).

For example:

Instead this:

```
import Component from '../../components/Component
```

I would like to use

```
import Component from 'components/Component
```

I've added this configuration on `config.js` file:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    components: './src/components'
  }
}
```

This `resolve.alias` enables aliases for projects bundled with webpack but doesn't working with React Starter Kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) with the full path:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    components: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components')
  }
}
```

Instead of using alias, I usually use [modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) to "mount" my entire `src` folder:

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    'node_modules',
  ],
```

which, assuming I have a dir structure like:

```
src/
src/components/...
src/util/...
src/routes/...
src/views/...
```

let's me write these sorts of imports:

```
import C from 'components/C';
import foo from 'util/foo';
import routes from 'routes/blah';
...
```

Comment: This solved part of my problem, in fact my issue was related with [this problem](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4817). Anyway, this approach is excelent to reach my goal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
import Component from 'components'
```

Comment: I got error message: `Can't resolve 'components' in '/Users/.../Container.js'`

Comment: webpack alias is trying to do it's thing for sure...  seems like the path might be off a bit tho.  Try to set it up like this.  http://xabikos.com/2015/10/03/Webpack-aliases-and-relative-paths/