# how to use absolute paths instead of relative paths in React or Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm using React and I have multiple components that I use in multiple higher-order components, my imports sometimes will be like this `import MyComponent from '../../../../components/MyComponent'` I know there is a more efficient way to import this by changing something inside the package.json file and then import it somewhat like this `import MyComponent from '@components/myComponent'` but I don't remember how can I do this, how can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290002/how-to-configure-module-alias-properly

Comment: Use jsconfig.json - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure module.alias properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290002/how-to-configure-module-alias-properly)

Comment: you mean aliases it depends on your project tool is it nextjs or CRA and you should see there

Comment: @eladBA it's NEXT.js

Comment: so you should go to their site and see how its done if I recall they use webpack pluging and you should configure it there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by using `jsconfig` or `tsconfig` if you're using TypeScript.

1. Add jsconfig.json file to the root of your project.
2. Add the below code in your jsconfig.json file.
3. Start your react app using the command `npm start`.

jsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

If you're using Next.js this may help
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm using Next.js the link you included answered my question. I'm using typescript so changing the `tsconfig.json` file did it for me.

Answer (score 6):

Create a jsconfig.json in the root directory and copy the below code. Restart VSCode for the changes to apply -

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in next.js, this works for me=>

In root folder,  create jsconfig.json( tsconfig.json if using typescript) file. Then add this

```
 { 
   "compilerOptions": { "baseUrl": "." },
   "include":["."]
 }
```

create a "components" folder in root file, then  it will be like this :

```
// components/button.js

export default function Button() {
  return <button>Click me</button>
}


// App.js

import Button from 'components/button'

 export default function HomePage() {
    return (
     <>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <Button />
     </>
   )
 }
```

Comment: If you are going to lift most of your answer and example from [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases), you should give credit to the source.

Comment: I don't know if it is mentioned in the doc. I got this in a BootCamp.

Answer (score 1):

### In Root add a file name *jsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./"
    },
    "include": ["./"],
    "exclude":["node_modules","build"]
}
```

### Then use like this

```
import ChatWindow from 'src/components/ChatWindow';
```

**Note:** this will cover

```
ROOT/src/components/ChatWindow.js
```

### !! Don't forget to rebuild !!